# My gallery won't move to the right

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

So I'm new to html, using someone else's gallery and code, and having a little trouble figuring out how it works.  I was able to add a top margin to the gallery (both by using margin and margin-top commands), but neither margin nor margin-left makes any difference in trying to move the gallery right.  I've pasted the CSS and relevant code below.

CSS

```
    ul.bjqs{position:absolute; list-style:none;padding:0;margin:100;overflow:hidden; display:none;}
    li.bjqs-slide{position:absolute; display:none;}
    ul.bjqs-controls{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;z-index:9999;}
    ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a{position:absolute;}
    ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-next a{right:0;}
    ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-prev a{left:0;}
    ol.bjqs-markers{list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;}
    ol.bjqs-markers.h-centered{text-align: center;}
    ol.bjqs-markers li{display:inline;}
    ol.bjqs-markers li a{display:inline-block;}
    p.bjqs-caption{display:block;width:96%;margin:0;padding:2%;position:absolute;bottom:0;}

    <div id="banner-fade" style="height: 306px; max-width: 460px; position: relative;">
    <div class="bjqs-wrapper" style="width: 460px; height: 306px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
```

html

```
    <div id="banner_container">
        <!--  Outer wrapper for presentation only, this can be anything you like -->
     <div id="banner-fade">
        <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
     <ul class="bjqs">
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let me say that your example code didn't provide a lot of material to help with. I copied it all verbatim and I still didn't see any content. I also can't see any of the jquery you are using. Are you using the cycle plugin? In basic, though, if margins are not working, you may want to set the element's position to `position:absolute;`, if that does not work, play around with `static;`, and `relative;`. You may also want to use the float property, such as `float:middle`. this is all how you position normal elements, and if you gave better example code, I might have helped you more. Just try flost and position in css. :)